# Total variation convergence of random matrices and convergence of empirical spectral distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices, limits-and-convergence

In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5713.pdf, on page 17, the authors prove in Theorem 7 that the total variation distance between the joint distribution of the entries of certain Wishart matrices $W(n,d)$ and the joint distribution of the entries of a (based on the) GOE matrix $M(n,d)$ converges to zero:
$$d_{TV}(W(n,d), M(n,d)) \to 0.$$
Below their result (Theorem 7), they state that:
"Theorem 7 states that all statistics  (e.g., the empirical spectral
distribution, or the largest eigenvalue) of the random matrix ensembles $W(n,d)$ and $M(n,d)$ have asymptotically the same distribution."

How can one infer this from $d_{TV}(W(n,d), M(n,d)) \to 0$ that all statistics have asymptotically the same distribution? In particular the empirical spectral distributions.
Is this because of the total variation distance? Would this not hold anymore if one had the Wasserstein distance instead?

In a broader view, does the total variation metric imply convergence of all the statistics related to the matrix?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Welcome to MO. Not editing your question, but you might want to consider rephrasing - is it really a question about this specific paper, or a broader question about total-variation metric on matrix distributions?

Comment: Thanks! I added a broader question at the end, I am wondering why this is true and how to show it.

Comment: It maybe depends on what you mean by "statistics".  It's true that if we have Borel probability measures $\mu_n \to \mu$ in total variation, then $\int f\,d\mu_n \to \int f\,d\mu$ for all bounded Borel functions $f$.  This follows quickly from the definition of total variation.  If you had convergence in Wasserstein distance instead, this would only be true for bounded *continuous* $f$.

Comment: Thank you Nate for your response! The "statistic" I am interrested in is the empirical spectral distribution of the matrix. The authors of that paper claim that if $d_{TV}(W(n,d), M(n,d)) \to 0$, then the all statistics of these two matrices, including the empirical spectral distribution, are the asymptotically the same. Is that true? And if so, why?